# How do I work with the latest version of solidity?

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

A [new version](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.23) of Solidity was added fairly recently, and one of the feature it adds is messages on `require`.

I would like to use them but I'm not sure how I can do that. I'm using Ganache and truffle, and I test my contracts with Remix.

Am I right to assume that Ganache does the compilation and execution of the code, and thus works with a specific version of Solidity? Or does it work with any version? If so, where does the new code come from? (It does everything locally)

Would it work with just changing the pragma or do I need to wait for a release of Ganache that supports the new version?

Comment: ganache doesn't do any compilation, you can check compile version `truffle version` then you can check compiler version as `Solidity v0.4.21 (solc-js)`.

Comment: @Kronos Thanks that's all I needed, you can write that as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ganache (testrpc) generates a block for each transaction. So every time, you send transactions, it generates new blocks. (But the ethereum mainnet generates new blocks every 15 secs, so you have to wait...) 
You can check the generated block number.

```
truffle(development)> web3.eth.blockNumber
web3.eth.blockNumber

truffle(development)> web3.eth.blockNumber
0
truffle(development)> web3.personal.unlockAccount("0x41401ae014f926be3d8583723144dc7138a6fb24")
true
truffle(development)> web3.eth.blockNumber
0
truffle(development)> 
truffle(development)> web3.eth.sendTransaction({from:"0x41401ae014f926be3d8583723144dc7138a6fb24",to:"0xfad23e5147ea907b6045efa97c5b208e1e510381",value: web3.toWei(0.1,"ether")})
truffle(development)> web3.eth.blockNumber
1
truffle(development)>
```

You can see the blockNumber hass increased. To get the compiler version, use `truffle version` then you see:

```
Truffle v4.1.7 (core: 4.1.7)
Solidity v0.4.23 (solc-js)
```

When truffle does not provide to change compiler version as Remix. You have to uninstall truffle and re-install different version to try in different compiler version. [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases) you can download different version of truffle with solidity compiler.

Comment: I didn't have to uninstall and reinstall Truffle. I used `npm install -g truffle` and it updated both truffle and solc.

Comment: I don't understand some of your sentences though, like the first one and "*When truffle does not provide to change compiler version as Remix*".

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. in Remix you can easily change compiler version using drop down UI, but truffle does not provide to do that. But as you said, updating truffle version works fine for normal use.